# R Loop over each URL, scrape, parse, extract nodes and put into a data frame

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, web-crawler, rcurl

> Using the following packages:  require(stringr) require(RCurl)
>   require(XML)
>
> I am able to connect to the desired web page, and extract information
>   needed.

```
> url="https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/33415/pg-1" doc =
> getURLContent(url, verbose = TRUE) #gets the doc , verbose = show me
> me what you are doing) doc = htmlParse(doc)
> # name =  getNodeSet(doc,  "//div[@itemprop = 'name']") name = sapply(name, xmlValue)
> # phone =  getNodeSet(doc,  "//div[@itemprop= 'telephone']") phone = sapply(phone, xmlValue)
```

> I generated a list of urls

```
urlList = c("https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/33415/pg-1",
                "https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/33415/pg-2")

    urlList = as.list(urlList)
```

> I would like to loop over each url, capture the same nodes and place
>   the results in one data frame consisting of columns called Name and
>   Phone.
>
> I tried the following with no success

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), 
       lapply(urls_list, function(x) {
         data.frame(urlList=x, 

                     # d<- htmlParse(getURLContent(x))
                    d<-htmlParse(d)
                    d1 =  getNodeSet(d,  "//div[@itemprop = 'name']")
                    name = sapply(name, xmlValue)

       })) -> results
```

Thank you  for all your help

Comment: *I tried the following with no success* ... is not helpful for us. What errors or undesired results occurred?

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work to get you the information you're after.

```
library(rvest)

zip.codes <- c("33415", "33413")

results <- list()

result.index <- 0

for(zip in zip.codes){

  url <- paste0("https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/", zip ,"/pg-1" )

  page <- read_html(url)

  max.pages <- as.numeric(max(page %>% 
                                html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="page"]') %>% 
                                html_nodes("a") %>% 
                                html_text))

  for(i in c(1:max.pages)){
    print(paste("Processing Zip Code", zip, "- Page", i, "of", max.pages))

    result.index <- result.index + 1

    url <- paste0("https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/", zip,"/pg-", i)

    page <- read_html(url)

    df <- data.frame(AgentID = page %>% 
                               html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="call_inquiry_cta"]') %>% 
                               xml_attr("data-agent-id"),
                     AgentName = page %>% 
                               html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="call_inquiry_cta"]') %>% 
                               xml_attr("data-agent-name"),
                     AgentAddr = page %>% 
                               html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="call_inquiry_cta"]') %>% 
                               xml_attr("data-agent-address"),
                     AgentPhone = sub("tel:", "", page %>% 
                                                  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="call_inquiry_cta"]') %>% 
                                                  xml_attr("href")),
                     PhoneType = page %>% 
                                 html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="call_inquiry_cta"]') %>% 
                                 xml_attr("data-agent-num-type"),
                     AgentWebSite = page %>% 
                                    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="call_inquiry_cta"]') %>% 
                                    xml_attr("data-agent-web-url"))

    results[[result.index]] <- df
  }
}

df <- do.call(rbind, results)
```

Comment: Never use `rbind` in a loop. It leads to excessive memory copying. See Patrick Burns' [R Interno: Circle 2 - Growing Objects](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: Generally good advice, especially when dealing with objects of varying length. I've tested this script both performing the rbind in the loop, and creating a list of data frames in the loop with the rbind after. In this particular case I actually found having the rbind inside the loop executed slightly faster, and there was no difference in the memory usage during execution of each method.

Comment: OP's needs can extend beyond this which can be a sample of a larger project. At small scales, differences are immaterial but a future reader can take your code to loop through thousands of pages. SO answers should usually aim for best practices.

Comment: Thank you.The code works well. Is is possible to nest this inside a loop that looks at multiple zip codes. for example if i wanted the data from the zips bellow also on that same data frame.  zipcodelist =c("33415", "33413"). Also, can I make the system wait a 10 seconds after each extraction? Thank you.

Comment: I've edited my answer to work with multiple zip codes, and switched the rbind to outside the loop, like @Parfait recommended. If you really want to add in a 10 second delay between transactions, then just a line with `Sys.sleep(10)` after the `results[[result.index]] <- df` line